# Disappear elements on hover in chrome, when using Wordpress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, google-chrome, hyperlink

I'm a software JS developer, who decides to create web app with Wordpress.

Everything goes fine, until I start implementing url link in footer.

So when I start testing results links and other elements "sometimes" disappear only in Chrome browser (on other browsers, issue never occurred). I tried everything that could cause this issue.

- open in incognito mode,
- do not using any builder,
- not including this links on footer, but also on the page
- analyzing style in devtools (the same for working veiw and not)

Video with the issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f1C5J-VHS5A&feature=youtu.be

My  page name is https://www.heracl.com/

Comment: check wheather any ads running on your chrome

Comment: Thank you, but I already tried in incognito mode, where no any ads. Also on my side I do not use ads.

Comment: I dint find any issue mentioned in your video on my chrome. browser